# UISlider custom thumb

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, customization, uislider

So i have a problem with customising my UISlider.

I put in a custom thumb which is bigger than the normal uislider thumb, but now the thumb wont slide to the very edges of the uislider, it will jst stop a few pixels before the end.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your thumb image does not have transparent pixels width...i.e.the colors should stretch to the width of the image..